# Передача данных между js и php при создании плагина на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Пишу плагин для расчета стоимости доставки интернет-магазина (woocommerce). У меня есть js-скрипт, который получает адрес и отдает расстояние в километрах до ближайшего филиала. Следуя [документации](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/), я создал шаблон плагина доставки и добавил туда возможность получать значения поля "адрес" в функции calculate_shipping(). Теперь, на сколько я понимаю, мне нужно передавать значение поля "адрес" в js-скрипт расчета, а потом получить из него (скорее всего ajax-запросом) расстояние в километрах. Вопрос в том как правильно это сделать? И можно ли вообще запустить js из php чтобы произвести расчет и получить обратно результат скрипта?

Скрипт не получится переписать на php, так как там я использую API Я.Карт.

Answer (score 1):

Запустить js скрипт из php можно, но назад в тот же php процесс результат получить нельзя.

Делать надо наоборот, используя ajax.

1. PHP выводит форму с полем адреса.
2. Js скрипт ждёт реакции пользователя, чтобы он выбрал адрес через Я.API.
3. Получив ответ пользователя, скрипт заполняет поле формы с адресом и отправляет расстояние в километрах в php через ajax.
4. Запускается новый процесс php, грузится ядро и плагины, ваш код получает управление и что-то там вычисляет (видимо, стоимость доставки).
5. Эту стоимость доставки php возвращает в js как результат ajax запроса.
6. Всё тот же скрипт, получив стоимость доставки, выводит её в нужном месте.